# How to find out in Vim which command is triggered by some shortcut

Tags: debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, introspection

I try to execute a command in some plugin by pushing it's keyboard shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd>. But some other command is executed, instead. But that command gives an error. So it is not clear where the key mapping of that interfering command is defined. I want to change the mapping of that shortcut. To do this I need to find out what that interfering command is.

Is there a way to find out which command is triggered by some keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
verbose map <F2>
```

will give you information about both {rhs} and place where this mapping was defined. For insert mode mappings replace `map` with `imap`, same for other mapping modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the shortcuts in ~/.vimrc file and ~/.vim/plugin/[you plugin name], maybe you find which action is bound to the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.