# How to set Vim print the command which I trigger by some shortcut I didn't configure

Tags: vim

I install some plugins by Vundle and manul. and I found the map I did: `map <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` was overrided by other plugins which return `E73: tag stack empty` after executed.

And my question is, how can I figure out which shortcut is executed by the `<C-t>` in Vim.

I'v check with `verbose map <C-t>` mentioned by
 [How to find out in Vim which command is triggered by some shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218035/how-to-find-out-in-vim-which-command-is-triggered-by-some-shortcut).

But I just got `No mapping found`.

Comment: this is a standard vim mapping see `:h CTRL-T`. The best starting point is the `verbose map` command as you tried. If there is nothing shown there it is a default mapping. Also a good starting point is the error message `:h E73`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in first trying

```
:verbose map <C-t>
```

first. If that doesn't give a result, it's a *built-in command*. You can look those up via

```
:help CTRL-T
```

(Note that the help uses a different key syntax.)

If the mysterious command gives you a `E...` error message, that's another good indication of a built-in command. You can then also directly look up the error; the related command usually is close to it.

```
:help E73
```

Comment: Sorry, this mostly just duplicates and expands on Doktor OSwaldo's comment, but after such a long time, I thought it appropriate to conclude this question.